# Where do I ask about maths terminology?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where is it appropriate to ask about mathematical terminology/language? (I would like to ask if a certain technical phrase is correct and/or appropriate for a maths paper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at [MathSE's Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions regarding mathematical concepts are allowed. Since we can say that writing mathematical statements concisely is also a concept in it's own right, such questions can be safely asked on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

In fact, they also have a tag called [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) with 4879 questions, so go ahead and ask it there.